# Recovery files from partclone backup image without generate a large raw disk file? (like Acronis mount tib file)?

Tags: partclone

I have a 100GB files stored in a 3TB hdd (NTFS).
I backuped it using partclone and resulted a 100GB partclone.pcl image file.
Now I want to recovery the files (I don't care about the MBR or other unnecessary staffs, I just need the files).

All tutorials online ask me to restore it to a sda1.raw dd image (probably will be 3TB?). As the partclone.pcl image can not be mounted.
The problem is I don't have a 3TB free disk space...  (external usb disks are too slow - not a good option)

I know linux are good at piping and redirecting. So is there a way to extract the 100GB files without generating a huge 3TB unless image file?